# Optaplanner contraint streams - how to check mutliple resources

Tags: kotlin, optaplanner

My domain is:

- Requirement with some Variants of its realization
- Any Variant need multiple resources with amount
- Any Resource has limit

I try to write conflict method

```
constraintFactory
.from(Requirement::class.java)
.groupBy(Requirement::variant::resourceUsageList, sum(Resource::amount))
...
```

but is doesn't work

How can I get all used resource with its used amount and compare it with resources limit?

I think I need something like flatmap after from.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your `List<Resource>` on your `@PlanningSolution` has a `@ProblemFactCollectionProperty`, so `from(Resource.class)` works.

Then I see multiple ways of doing it:

Proposal A)

```
from(Requirement.class)
.join(Resource.class) // Bi<Requirement, Resource>
.groupBy((requirement, resource) -> resource, sum((requirement, resource) -> requirement.variant.resourceUsage[resource.index]))
...
```

The downside is that this proposal A creates a Cartesian Product, so it can be costly memory wise if you have 100 resources and 10 000 requirements.

Propsal B)

```
.from(Requirement::class.java)
.groupBy(Requirement::variant::resourceUsageList, new MyResourceUsageSumCollector(...))
...
```

For `MyResourceUsageSumCollector`, which sums for each resource, look at this sum which sums for just one long for inspiration:

```
public static <A> UniConstraintCollector<A, ?, Long> sumLong(ToLongFunction<? super A> groupValueMapping) {
    return new DefaultUniConstraintCollector<>(
            () -> new long[1],
            (resultContainer, a) -> {
                long value = groupValueMapping.applyAsLong(a);
                resultContainer[0] += value;
                return () -> resultContainer[0] -= value;
            },
            resultContainer -> resultContainer[0]);
}
```